# css3 new selectors target on hover

Tags: css, css-selectors, target

Is there a way in css3 to target a div on hover, so if I have an sturucture like below could I target the divs as direct siblings of the h1?

```
<h1>item1</h1>
<div>this is the description for 1</div>

<h1>item2</h1>
<div>this is the description for 2</div>

<h1>item3</h1>
<div>this is the description for 3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) for this:

```
h1 + div:hover { ... }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9P2hd/

W3C is your friend (at least most of the time): http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/